# Record color and depth video KINECT C#

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, video-recording

I want to record a video from my KINECT for the color and depth frames, one video for color frames and another for depth frames. I wanna do this in C# WPF Application..

any ideas about how to do this ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to store it raw/lossless or are you fine using a usual video codec? The rgb stream is a usual video sequence that could be encoded just well with a codec. However, the depth stream is storing 11 bits of depth information per pixel. If you dont mind the loss in information, you could reduce this to a 8 bit greyscale image stream. That all depends on what you want to do with the recording afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/) Library. It is able to use Kinect for both color and depth. Check out [this](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html) example (bottom of page). The Kinect namespace is [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/5b555f97-4a0c-0d7d-13ff-814998336930.htm). It includes both a KinectVideoCamera (color) and KinectDepthCamera.

AForge is easily integrated with WPF. If you need examples on using AForge with WPF, [here](http://www.kclbot.com/academic/tutorial-wpf-c-kinect-sdk-aforge-net-gratf-glyph-tracking/) is one, or just search the web.

Then of course, there is always the option of using [Emgu cv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). [Here](http://www.geek-press.com/?p=23) is one example of it with kinect.

Comment: -1 You dont really answer the question. The op wanted to know how to **record** those streams, not how to get them. Also, why should he use AForge.NET, that in turn uses libfreenect if he doesnt want to computervision with it (he didnt say anything about that). I would recommend the official Kinect SDK: www.kinectforwindows.org